# How to use GIT in web development team

Tags: git, web

I am trying to implement GIT in my company for web development.
Our current workflow is:

1. Implementing and testing features on a test server in our environment
2. Copy/Paste the files on the production server.

Now I am trying to figure out how I would do this with GIT.

My idea is that the developers should push changes on the local(test) server and when the project is finished the production server will pull the updates.

My question is how the test server will see the git files?
Do you have any recommendations for this approach?

Comment: It will be helpful to explain the -1 in a comment

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a good idea to push **to** the test server. Since shared repository is usually a **bare** repository.

It would be best to keep the shared repository somewhere on a third server.
Everyone can push to this server, and you can maintain several branches there if you wish.

The test server pulls the changes before running the test.
Or for a more complete test - it would clone the entire repository fresh each time before test.

Answer (score 0):

There are really plenty of approaches to this problem, you should consider read more about "Auto deployment", "GIT + deploy" etc.

Personally I'm using special script to export all the files between specific tags in GIT repository and upload them directly on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the git workflow(s) modal.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/
http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

You simply have to figure out which workflow suits you the best and you can grab the most suitable one.

If you choose to use [nvie gitworkflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) you can customize it to your own needs by modifing teh scripts